# How to create a Workflow field instance in a node?

Tags: 7, entities, workflows

I want to add programatically an instance of a workflow field into the article content type.

This is how far I got:

```
<?php
// Create the field singleton
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_workflow',
  'type' => 'workflow',
);
$field = field_create_field($field);

// Create the instance on the bundle.
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => $field['field_name'],
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle' => 'article',
  'label' => 'State',
  'description' => 'Workflow state information',
  'settings' => array( 'wid' => $workflow->wid ),
  'widget' => array( 'type' => 'workflow_default' ),
  'display' => array(
    'default' => array('label' => 'hidden' ),
  ),
);
```

Everything works fine except it doesn't assign the workflow to the field. The workflow has all the states and transitions defined. I can add it manually using the ui.

I added the setting `'wid' => $workflow->wid` but it doesn't update it.

How can it be done?

---

Extract of the Bundle copy export for the workflow field created manually:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  'bundles' => array(
    ...
  ),
  'fields' => array(
    'field_workflow' => array(
      'settings' => array(
        'allowed_values_function' => 'workflowfield_allowed_values',
        'wid' => '17',
        'widget' => array(
          ...
        ),
        ...
      ),
      ...
    ),
  ),
  'instances' => array(
    'field_workflow' => array(
      0 => array(
        'label' => 'Workflow',
        'widget' => array(
          ...
        ),
        'settings' => array(
          'user_register_form' => FALSE,
        ),
        'display' => array(
          ...
        ),
        'field_name' => 'field_workflow',
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Try to install the module bundle copy. Add the workflow field yo your content type, export the content type en check the array that bundle copy constructs for you. Let me know if this helps you out

Comment: Thanks @Robin. I added the export I obtained in the bundle export. There is only one reference to the worflow id (wid) in the field settings.

Comment: so it is still not working as intended?

Comment: Doesn't work. when creating the instance automatically if I export the field with bundle copy `$data['fields']['field_workflow']['settings']['wid']` is not set.